# Command to open url in firefox 57 in window without tab and searchbar

Tags: firefox, shortcuts

I'd like to create a shortcut to open a URL in a window using Firefox 57 Quantum.

However, I'd like the window to have the native borders and header, but not have the tab-bar, the search-bar, etc.

I looked at the command line switches, but didn't see such an option.  Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly not firefox 57, but since firefox 71 the [option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options#--kiosk_url) `--kiosk` exist. Maybe it helps.